# Laravel Envoyer Deployment Hook Install Composer Dependencies Failed

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.6, envoyer.io, laravel-envoy

We are using for Laravel Deployment the Envoyer platform.

We have the problem that the Deployment Hook "Install Composer Dependencies" stops at 600 Seconds on one server.

So the Deployment does not go through since days.

I found the possibility to set a config param "process-timeout" in the composer.json but nothing happens. That is not considered.

I have no idea where I should still look to change this value or increase.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to increase deployment hook timeouts? I have this issue

Answer (score 0):

I asked this from envoyer support and they said they have no plans to change the 600s timeout. You should optimize your deployments